# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LS.settings'

Tags: python, django, cmd, project

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LS.settings'
LS is my project name

```
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\LS\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LS.settings'
```

I tried to change my settings.py file and wsgi.py too.. but nothing worked
In settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.Path.dirname(os.Path.dirname(os.Path.dirname(__file__)))

#settings
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-4o%nqtij3bmt!v)74+p@7d!t8w&u98&l&5%55fc81pw$$$tjx&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Comment: please share whole settings.py file

Comment: i added settings.py file above